# To Update Content on App, is NSURLConnection the best way to go?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, objective-c, xcode

Right now I can update content on my app by connecting to my website using NSURLConnection.  However, it seems messy.  Trying to organize the words onto a label is difficult.  Also, for each new label containing new content, would I have to connect to a new web page each time?

Basically, is there a better way to update content on ones app, similar to a news page?

Answer (score 0):

`NSURLConnection` is the definitely way to go. All it does is a very robust and tested way to connect to your web site asynchronously and retrieve the content. And it is not messy. You make the connection and then catch the results in the callback once it is finished.

The issues you cite in your concerns are all not related at all to the way you connect to your web site. It is up to you to structure the data in a meaningful way, say, in a JSON format or otherwise. Once you have retrieve your `NSData` object it is up to you to display the data efficiently in suitable UIKit objects, such as tableview cells, labels, or text views, etc.

Comment: Big thanks for the input, its nice to know Im going down the right path.  Ill be looking into JSON and learning about how to display the content properly.